# Magento 1.9.2.3 : cannot show associated product of grouped product

Tags: admin, grouped-products, ce-1.9.2.3

How to fix this error when i will display the associated product of a grouped product from the admin.
The error log indicates : Unknown column 'position' in 'order clause' in the table `catalog_product_entity`

Here is the log :

SELECT `e`.*, `at_status`.`value` AS `status`, `links`.`link_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '96') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 0)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_link` AS `links` ON links.linked_product_id = e.entity_id AND links.link_type_id = 3 WHERE (((`e`.`required_options` != '1') OR (`e`.`required_options` IS NULL))) AND (at_status.value IN(1, 2)) AND (links.product_id = 1015) AND (`e`.`entity_id` != '1015') ORDER BY `position` ASC
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'position' in 'order clause', query was: SELECT `e`.*, `at_status`.`value` AS `status`, `links`.`link_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '96') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 0)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_link` AS `links` ON links.linked_product_id = e.entity_id AND links.link_type_id = 3 WHERE (((`e`.`required_options` != '1') OR (`e`.`required_options` IS NULL))) AND (at_status.value IN(1, 2)) AND (links.product_id = 1015) AND (`e`.`entity_id` != '1015') ORDER BY `position` ASC

Comment: It is an SQL query, you should tell us the error you get from error.log.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on my Magento (hopefully this is the same for you).
I think it's due to Magmi, I used it to import my products.

The problem was that the table "catalog_product_link_attribute" was empty, and then the column "product_link_attribute_id" in "catalog_product_link_attribute_int" table was always set to "NULL".

I did a fresh install of Magento and created a grouped product to have a functional grouped product sample and here are the data if you want for the table "catalog_product_link_attribute" :

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_link_attribute` (`product_link_attribute_id`, `link_type_id`, `product_link_attribute_code`, `data_type`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'position', 'int'),
(2, 3, 'position', 'int'),
(3, 3, 'qty', 'decimal'),
(4, 4, 'position', 'int'),
(5, 5, 'position', 'int');
```

Once you've entered these rows into your database, simply update "product_link_attribute_id"" field from "catalog_product_link_attribute_int" to "2" and it should be fine!

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Well thank you for your help. This liberated catalog access.

Comment: Glad it worked for you too :) Be careful if you reuse Magmi for grouped products, I assume this was the reason it failed ;) Or maybe it will work now that your "catalog_product_link_attribute" table isn't empty anymore, I didn't try a new import :)